# List Manipulation - TemporalData on Uneven List

Tags: list-manipulation, time-series

I would like ask you a question about using `TemporalData` on an uneven list. For example, suppose I have following lists:

```
list1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

list2 = {1, 2, 3};
```

I want to match each component in `list1` to components in `list2`. My ultimate goal is to make a `ListPlot` with large data sets. In other words, `y = {1, 2, 3, 4}` at `x = 1`,`y = {5, 6}` at `x = 2` and `y = {7, 8, 9}` at `x = 3`. I tried `Transpose` and `TemporalData`, but it turns out that these commands cannot handle uneven lists. Could you give me any advice? Thanks

Comment: I think you can't avoid balancing the sublists in `list1`; after doing so, either approach listed in the question can lead to the desired result (at least as far as the example in the question is concerned)

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you seek, either one of the following should work (using your list definitions):

```
MapThread[Distribute[{#1, #2}, List] &, {list2, list1}]

(* or *)

MapThread[Thread[{#1, #2}, List] &, {list2, list1}]


(* Out: 
{
 {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}}, 
 {{2, 5}, {2, 6}}, 
 {{3, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 9}}
}
*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your solutions to my data sets and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

This is how `TemporalData` can be used to solve the problem:

```
ListLinePlot[#, 
  Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic]&@With[{mx = Max[Length /@ #]},
  Quiet@TemporalData[
    Transpose[PadRight[#, mx, Missing[]] & /@ #], {list2},  
      MissingDataMethod -> {"Interpolation", InterpolationOrder -> 0}]
    ] &@list1
```

Evaluating the code above produces

[image]

There are 4 paths in the `TemporalData` object; the first two contain three observations (`{1, 5, 7}` and `{2, 6, 8}` respectively) while the last two contain varying number of numerical observations each (namely `{3, Missing[], 9}` and `{4, Missing[], Missing[]}` respectively).

The `Missing[]` entries get replaced by the previous numerical value in each path, courtesy of the value of the `MisingDataMethod` supplied to the `TemporalData` object.

---

Using `Transpose` (in a broad sense) can produce the same result

```
ListLinePlot[#, 
  Mesh -> All, Frame -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic] &@With[{mx = Max[Length /@ #]},
  Transpose[
    Apply[Thread[{##}] &, 
      Thread[{list2, PadRight[#, mx, Missing[]] & /@ #}], 1]]
     ] &@list1
```

[image]

(this time there is no interpolation for `Missing[]` values)

Answer (score 1):

```
Inner[
 Thread@*List
 , list2
 , list1
 , List
 ]
```

or

```
Map[
 Thread,
 Transpose[{list2, list1}]
 ]
```

in case you want the values grouped by abscissa value. Otherwise, wrap either function with `Flatten[ ... ,1]`.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried your answer to my data sets and got what I have expected.